# how to remove all formulas from an excel sheet by java POI api?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-formula

we can remove formula from one cell by cell.setCellFormula(null) .
but if i want to make the whole sheet formula free.

Comment: presumably you would use some form of iteration over all the cells?

Comment: Loop through the cells of the sheet, calling cell.setCellFormula(null).  I don't know about a global function that will change all cells.

Comment: yes it is one way but I was wondering if there is any method to do that in one go.

Comment: Could you not use a way to copy the whole sheet and paste it back as values only instead of looping through each and every cell? I don't use the Java POI API, so I can't help, but in VBA this is easy and quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Apache POI site](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) that exactly answers your question.