# How to remove all formulas from workbook with Java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, array-formulas

The same question was asked here a few years ago: 
[how to remove all formulas from an excel sheet by java POI api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991820/how-to-remove-all-formulas-from-an-excel-sheet-by-java-poi-api).

However, it did not receive an answer at the time that works for me.
I have a workbook with several large sheets and want to loop over all cells to replace the cell contents with strings. The problem is, many cells contain formulas which I have to get rid of first.  Neither `cell.setCellFormula(null)` nor `cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING)` (nor `BLANK`) is satisfying, as the underlying processes to remove array formulas take ages and make the entire job far too slow.

The following works but leaves a corrupt excel workbook which can only be opened with a repairing step on the first time:
`Method m = XSSFCell.class.getDeclaredMethod("setBlank");`
`m.setAccessible(true);`
`m.invoke(cell);`
Is there any other fast and cleaner way to simply set certain cells blank, regardless of any formulas?

Comment: How long does it take to `setCellForumla(null)` or `setCellType(CellType.STRING)`? Is it quicker to create another sheet/workbook by copying the non formula cells to the new sheet and delete the old sheet/workbook?

Answer (score 2):

The problem why the corrupted workbook occurs is that there is a calculation chain stored in `/xl/calcChain.xml`. The normal slow methods to remove the formulas will updating this calculation chain. But, as you found already, they also attempt to be usable for removing single formulas only and not all. So they must be carefully while removing parts of array formulas which makes them slow.

But if really **all** formulas shall be removed, this carefulness is not necessary and then simply the whole `/xl/calcChain.xml` can be removed.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CalculationChain;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellFormulaType;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class ExcelRemoveFormulasAndCalcChain {

 private static void removeCalcChain(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws Exception {
  CalculationChain calcchain = workbook.getCalculationChain();
  Method removeRelation = POIXMLDocumentPart.class.getDeclaredMethod("removeRelation", POIXMLDocumentPart.class); 
  removeRelation.setAccessible(true); 
  removeRelation.invoke(workbook, calcchain);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Test.xlsx"));

  for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     XSSFCell xssfcell = (XSSFCell)cell;
     if (xssfcell.getCTCell().isSetF() && xssfcell.getCTCell().getF().getT() != STCellFormulaType.DATA_TABLE) {
      xssfcell.getCTCell().unsetF();
     }
    }
   }
  }

  removeCalcChain(workbook);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("Test_1.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

This should remove all formulas and let all cells back containing only the values and styles.

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing  link.

Comment: You can also avoid the reflection via inheritance from XSSFWorkbook:   `public class NoFormulaWorkbook extends XSSFWorkbook {  
    public NoFormulaWorkbook(File file) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {  
        super(file);  
        removeRelation(getCalculationChain());  
    }  
}`

Comment: user8656003 - it's been a while but do you maybe want to mark @Axel Richter's answer as correct?

Comment: @gordon613 The user hasn't been on SO for years. Lots of users ask one question and never return. Don't worry about acceptance marks, they are completely optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to find how to remove formulas in some cell range.
I noticed that if I delete sheet first formulas with link to it are deleted fast.
If I swap deleting of formulas and deleting of sheets it takes a lot of time.
So if we create a sheet, rewrite all formulas using link to it, and delete sheet, formulas are removed fast (setting formulas with link to non-existing sheet doesn't work).
It takes seconds for 15k+ rows. Here is the experiment:

```
    File fReport = new File(".xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fReport));
    XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheet("");

    XSSFSheet dummy = book.createSheet("dummy");

    int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 8; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        XSSFRow rowToClean = sheet.getRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = rowToClean.getCell(2);
        System.out.println(i);
        if (cell != null) {
            cell.setCellFormula("'dummy'!A1");
        }
    }
    book.removeSheetAt(book.getSheetIndex(dummy));
    
    for (int i = 8; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        XSSFRow rowToClean = sheet.getRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = rowToClean.getCell(2);
        System.out.println(i);
        if (cell != null) {
            cell.removeFormula();
        }
    }

    book.write(new FileOutputStream(fReport));
    book.close();
```